# android messagebox

Tags: android, messagebox

I need to display a msgbox in the onFinish method of mu main activty.
But I get the following exception :

android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@43202998 is not valid; is your activity running?

No, my activity is not running, I'm in the onFinish treatment, but I doesn't have any other context...

Comment: are you showing your message box before super.onFinish()? try doing that. you should be able to show the dialog, before the activity actually is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declate this property in your activity

```
Activity activity = this;
```

And then:

```
public onFinish(){
    AlertDialog dialog = new AlerDialog.Builder(activity).create();
    dialog.setTitle("Title");
    //Add a message or buttons
    dialog.show();
}
```